# How to provide explicit type declarations for functions when using GHCi?

Tags: haskell, types, ghci, function-declaration

How to I define the equivalent of this function (taken from [learnyouahaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)) inside GHCi?

```
import Data.List  

numUniques :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Int  
numUniques = length . nub
```

Without the type declaration, GHCi accepts the function definition, but it ends up with an unhelpful type:

```
Prelude Data.List> import Data.List 
Prelude Data.List> let numUniques' = length . nub
Prelude Data.List> :t numUniques'
numUniques' :: [()] -> Int
```

The resulting function only accepts a list of units as a parameter.

Is there a way provide type declarations in GHCi? Or is there another way to define functions like these which doesn't require type declarations?

I saw no obvious clues in the GHCi guide, and experimented with expressions like the following (to no avail):

```
> let numUniques' = ((length . nub) :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Int)
> :t numUniques'
numUniques' :: [()] -> Int
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

> Is there a way provide type declarations in GHCi?

```
let numUniques' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Int; numUniques' = length . nub
```

> Or is there another way to define functions like these which doesn't require type declarations?

If you turn off the monomorphism restriction with `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`, it will infer the right type.

Comment: I'm not yet there with the monomorphism, but generally this answer pointed me to using semicolons to group together definitions in GHCi - tutorials are written like in a .hs file, which gives many different problems when tried in GHCi (functions lacks binding etc.).

Comment: It's worth noting that `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` is enabled by default for GHCi since 7.8.1: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#monomorphism

Answer (score 14):

The GHC User's Guide shows two additional ways to achieve this. [This subsection](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:%7B) introduces the `:{` ... `:}` construct, which can be used as follows:

```
> :{
| numUniques :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Int
| numUniques = length . nub
| :}
```

Alternatively, you can enable [multiline mode](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#multiline-input):

```
> :set +m
> let
| numUniques :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Int
| numUniques = length . nub
|
```

Answer (score 13):

Note that you can also avoid the monomorphism restriction simply by adding "points" (i.e. explicit variables) back to your expression. So this also gives the correct type:

> let numUniques x = length . nub $ x

Comment: This is known as eta-expansion