# function definitions in haskell interactive

Tags: haskell, types

```
factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n = product [1..n]
```

The following is fine:

```
let factorial n = product [1..n]
```

I do not see how to add type declarations in interactive shell.

Comment: Why do you want to add type declarations? Haskell will always attach the most generic signature to the function. In this case: `(Enum a, Num a) => a -> a`

Comment: For testing purposes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to provide explicit type declarations for functions when using GHCi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093133/how-to-provide-explicit-type-declarations-for-functions-when-using-ghci)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to specify the type signature yourself you can do this in ghci using semicolons, i.e.:

```
let factorial :: Integer -> Integer; factorial n = product [1..n]
```

Comment: To be super picky, the reason this works is that it is one statement, a let statement containing two declarations. It parses as `let { factorial :: Integer -> Integer; factorial n = product [1..n] }`.

Answer (score 5):

Next to the multi-line settings explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846050/how-to-define-a-function-in-ghci-across-multiple-lines), you can use this instead if you don't want to write semicolons.

```
λ> :{
λ> | let factorial :: Integer -> Integer
λ> |     factorial n = product [1..n]
λ> :}
λ> :t factorial
factorial :: Integer -> Integer
```

Comment: Tip: You can put a newline after the `let` and then don't need to indent the rest.